# generate many random letters with php

Tags: php

I want to make a lot of random words i already have the code to create one

```
function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}
echo generateRandomString();
```

can anyone tell me how to make them  more without clicking refresh all day?

Comment: Call the function in a loop ?!

Comment: And remember that *random* is a state of mind.

Comment: @Rizier123 i did it doesnt work

Comment: Then show how you tried it with a loop

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}

for ($i=0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    echo generateRandomString() . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Strange when i tried it didnt work, anyway thanks but do you know how to make them legit words like marashl19994 something like that?

Comment: Something like this might be a good start:
function generateRandomString($length = 6) {
    $characters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';

    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString . rand();
}